# Means originating from distributions of different variances - DV of interest

Tags: anova

I want to compare two means (repeated measures) that have very different variances of the underlying distributions (see screenshot below), confirmed by Levine's test.

[image: screenshot]

Since a comparison of the means using a paired t-test or 1-way ANOVA would not be allowed given the violation of the homogeneity of variances assumption, I am wondering whether I can report a statistic that is not about the means but about the difference in variances itself.

For this particular dataset, it is actually meaningful that the cross-subject variability in the second condition is smaller than in the first condition. What would be the most relevant statistic to report?

Comment: What's the response variable (the DV)? Is it necessarily positive, for example?

Comment: The DV in this case is response accuracy (0 to 1), although I have  a similar situation for when the DV is percentage change from scan 1 to scan 2, i.e. (scan2-scan1)/scan1

Comment: It can't be on 0 to 1, since the mean of the first group above is at 2. Can you account for how a 0-1 variable can be 2?

Comment: I inserted the screenshot just by way of illustration - as I said one of the variables is "%/proportion change" - that must be the one illustrated. For the 0-1 DV though, the plot looks qualitatively the same. Hopefully this clarifies it.

Comment: Please let me know if the question makes more sense now, thanks

Comment: Still havent found a satisfactory answer to this, would appreciate any other thoughts, thanks

Comment: Is response accuracy based on a count (such as a proportion correct), or is it derived some other way?

Comment: it is indeed based on a count, i.e. %correct or in some cases A-to-B %change

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to deal with differences in variance in ANOVA using Welch-Satterthwaite approach.

Since you are dealing with what seems like a proportion (whether continuous or discrete) and a ratio (minus 1) there are other choices than ANOVA; for example GLMs or extensions may be able to deal with the variance-related-to-mean that appears to be occuring

> Since a comparison of the means using a paired t-test

Would a *paired* t-test require equal means? You'd start by taking differences and all you'd need would be that the differences had the required properties.

Are the data actually paired?

> whether I can report a statistic that is not about the means but about the difference in variances itself.

Certainly. For that matter, even if you couldn't *test* the means (which I believe you can, if you have a suitable procedure), you could still report a statistic (such as the difference in means).

> For this particular dataset, it is actually meaningful that the cross-subject variability in the second condition is smaller than in the first condition. What would be the most relevant statistic to report?

We can't tell you what is most relevant for your purposes. A ratio of variances might be reasonably suitable as a statistic to report, but if you wanted to use a hypothesis test, I wouldn't use the corresponding ratio-of-variances test. Maybe Levene's test or Browne-Forsythe or something along those lines (but if there really is some kind of pairing present I'd want to understand that before suggesting anything).

Comment: Thanks! The pairing refers to two different within-subject conditions, namely in ConditionA subjects do the task with a certain set of instructions, while in ConditionB they receive slightly different instructions but the task stays the same